# Android - org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:

Tags: android, build.gradle

I am building an android application in which I tried to integrate [Firebase Performance Monitoring](https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon).  In the documentation it is mentioned that I need to add the following line in the **project level** build.gradle

```
classpath 'com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.3.4'
```

I have misplaced this dependency in **app level** build.grade by replacing the `classpath` with `implementation`. I have realized the mistake I made and then tried to move the dependency to project level **build.gradle** file but I am getting the following exception.

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
```

I have even tried removing `.gradle` folder from the project location and restarted the Android studio but still facing the same issue.

Please help me find the solution.